# VS2010 Image library, what is the use of the different size pngs?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, imagelibrary

The VS2010 image library contains several pngs of standard icons (Warning, Error, ...) in different sizes side by side.  What is the use of such a png?

1. Is it meant as source to cut the best size and save it as new png?
2. Or is there a way to use such a png and the best resolution is picked automatically. And if so, how is this done?

I wonder why there are such side-by-side images and not several files such as Warning32.png, Warning16.png ....

Example: `Information.png`

[image: Example of side by side image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an old programming trick and it is exactly what you assume it to be. The bitmap is a "film roll" and to make it work you have to know the pitch of the images, the resource doesn't tell you. Hard-coded in the source code. Microsoft's source code, you got the copy of their work.